# Touches in subview calling superview's method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, touchesbegan, touches

I have two classes, `BoxNinjaViewController` (the default view created by Xcode) and `GameClass`. GameClass is loaded as a subview, like so:

```
GameClass *game = [[GameClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"GameClass" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview: game.view];
```

The GameClass view appears like normal, but when I try to add the `touchesBegan:` method, it acts funny.

In BoxNinjaViewController.m, I have:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"sauce");
}
```

and in GameClass.m, I have:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"tuna");
}
```

...and when I click in GameClass's view, it NSLogs

```
2013-05-26 14:54:24.908 BoxNinja[75023:c07] sauce
```

Any Ideas on what's going on, and how I could fix it? This his how I've set up all my previous apps, and I've never had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, making the `game` object a property of `BoxNinjaViewController` fixed it. I guess it stopped it from being autoreleased or something?